# My button is not formatting even though I set the background colour, size, etc. in css already

Tags: html, css, button

I'm making a website and I'm trying to make the button center aligned, border-less, however, the css codes doesn't seem to effect the website

I have tried changing the class name, changing around the code and such. On the browser (google chrome) it shows that the code is "recognized" on the style but isn't being read

```css
.qwerty {
  background:#f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<div class="column" class="Border">
 <form action="aboutme.html">
 <button class="qwerty">ABOUT ME</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

The button should have no border, orange, and increases opacity on hover

Comment: Seems like it works fine except for the hover effect. The hover effect is broken because the css is looking for a class called `button` and not finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You treat button as a class (in the CSS part where you have a dot before "button"). You can either write either of these two:

```css
// First solution
.qwerty:hover {opacity: 1}

//Second solution
button:hover {opacity: 1}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
.column {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

use this. parent div must have a specific width to make child div it's center.